# Randomly distribute r balls in n boxes. Find the probability that the rst box is empty

Tags: probability

Question: Randomly distribute r balls in n boxes. Find the probability that the first box is empty.

I think I should make the question into 3 cases, namely, r=n, r<n, and r>n.

CASE r=n:

${r \choose 2}$ because there are two balls of r balls that will be put into the same box.

${n-1 \choose 1}$ because we choose one box that will put the two balls.

$(r-2)!$ put the rest r-2 balls into the rest n-2 boxes.

$$\frac{{r \choose 2} {n-1 \choose 1} (r-2)! }{r^{n}}$$

CASE r>n:
$$(\frac{n-1}{n})^r$$

CASE r<n:
$$\frac{{(n-1)Pr}}{nPr}$$

Am I on the right track? Please give me some advice, thank you!

Comment: If by "randomly" you mean *independently* and *uniformly,* then there's no need to break into cases: apply the definition of independence to compute the chance that all balls are in boxes 2, 3, ..., n.

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: What is the probability that the *first* ball ends up in box 2, ..., n? What is the probability that the *second* ball ends up in box 2, ..., n?

Answer (score 0):

Just because the first box is empty doesn't mean all the other boxes aren't.

$$
P(1\text{st box empty})=1-P(1\text{st not empty})
$$

If you "give" the first box 1 ball, you are left with r-1 balls and n boxes, you can express it as:
$$
x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_n=r-1
$$

The sample space similarly is:
$$
x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_n=r
$$

Using stars and bars method:
$$
P(1\text{st box empty})=1-\dfrac{\binom{n+r-2}{r-1}}{\binom{n+r-1}r}
$$

Comment: Isn't the answer simply $(1 - 1/n)^r$?